# Which XML-RPC library do you recommend for Android?

Tags: android, web-services, service, xml-rpc

I need to make my client talk to a XML-RPC service. I found a couple of interesting ones on the web like android-xmlrpc. Have you used any such libraries in your code? Which library do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it too and the library is quite awesome. Sample project is very informative so nothing more needed. 
Just go to http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/ and download sources.

Answer (score 0):

yes I have used the following stuff for xmlrpc responce in android
http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/beginners.php